# Gradle Native - Dynamically add libs in repository

Tags: groovy, gradle, dependency-management, build.gradle

I'm porting several Makefile projects in Gradle. I want every dependency to be versioned, so I created a common gradle file, namely general.gradle, that is included in each specific build.gradle file. For every project there is also a file dependencies.gradle, that contains a map {dependencyName, version}. Here an example:

```
ext.versions  = [:]    
versions.'libraryA'= "8a3f32"
versions.'libraryB'= "4af3e5"
```

I declare what libraryX refers to in general.gradle, inserting the libraries in the repositories, as follows:

```
repositories {        
 libs(PrebuiltLibraries) {        
  libraryA {
      def libraryName = "${name}"
      headers.srcDir "../${libraryName}"
      binaries.withType(SharedLibraryBinary) {                     
        sharedLibraryFile = file("${baseDir}/lib/${targetPlatform.name}/${buildType.name}/lib${libraryName}_" + versions."${libraryName}" + ".so")
       }         
   }

   libraryB {
      def libraryName = "${name}"
      headers.srcDir "../${libraryName}"
      binaries.withType(SharedLibraryBinary) {                    
         sharedLibraryFile = file("${baseDir}/lib/${targetPlatform.name}/${buildType.name}/lib${libraryName}_" + versions."${libraryName}" + ".so")
      }         
   }

   libraryC {....}
   libraryD {....}
}
```

By this way, I can also set the right path depending on build type (debug or release) and platform (x86 or x86_64).

As you can see, inside every libraryX there is the very same code. I was wondering if I could avoid this unnecessary duplication, using a list

```
libraries = [ "libraryA", "libraryB", ...]
```

I tried doing:

```
repositories {        
      libs(PrebuiltLibraries) {        
       [ "libraryA", "libraryB", ...].each {
        it {
          def libraryName = "${name}"
          headers.srcDir "../${libraryName}"
          binaries.withType(SharedLibraryBinary) {                    
             sharedLibraryFile = file("${baseDir}/lib/${targetPlatform.name}/${buildType.name}/lib${libraryName}_" + versions."${libraryName}" + ".so")
          }         
       }
     }                
    }
```

but I got this error:

```
Exception thrown while executing model rule: model.repositories   > No signature of method: java.lang.String.call() is applicable for argument types: (general_dt1njom2wz075lo490p9e44em$_run_closure3_closure24_closure25_closure26_closure29) values: 
[general_dt1njom2wz075lo490p9e44em$_run_closure3_closure24_closure25_closure26_closure29@2b2954e1]        
     Possible solutions: wait(), any(), wait(long), take(int), each(groovy.lang.Closure), any(groovy.lang.Closure)
```

Any idea?

Thanks,
Mauro

Comment: Can you try replacing `it {` with `"$it" {`

Comment: @tim-yates Unfortunately it doesn't work. this is the output:
`> Could not locate library 'libraryA'.
> NativeLibrarySpec with name 'libraryA' not found.
> Prebuilt library with name 'libraryA' not found in repositories '[libs]'.`

and if I print the variable `libraryName` I see it's assigned the value $it

Comment: try `delegate."$it" {`

Answer (score 0):

At this context `it` is a `String` variable:

```
[ "libraryA", "libraryB", ...].each {
    it {
```

You cannot call it, it's not a method.

A method you want to call is *delegated* to closure, defined in third party context, but you can refer to it by using `delegate`:

```
[ "libraryA", "libraryB", ...].each {
    delegate."$it" {
```

See also: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_delegation_strategy